# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim' in ax.plt_wireframe()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Matplotlib code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [5,6,7,8,2,5,6,3,7,2]
z = [1,2,6,3,2,7,3,3,7,2]

ax1.plot_wireframe(x,y,z)
ax1.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax1.set_zlabel('z axis')

plt.show()
```

Error output:

[image: OUTPUT WITH ERROR]

Expected output:

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

Comment: convert the list using `x = np.array(x)` to numpy array

Comment: python list doesnt have ndim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your data are 1D lists, but [`plot_wireframe`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_wireframe) expects 2D arrays:

> **Parameters:**
>
> `X`, `Y`, `Z` : 2D arrays

So convert the 1D lists -> 2D lists -> 2D arrays, e.g. `x` -> `[x]` -> `np.array([x])`:

```py
ax1.plot_wireframe(np.array([x]), np.array([y]), np.array([z]))
```

[image: wireframe output]